# Only initialize global variable if iOS Version is 8 or higher?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I would like to use SKLightNode in my new game. As you might know iOS 7.1 does not support SKLightNode. I would still like to use it for the ones that are on 8.0 or higher. The users with 7.1 or less will have to play without the lighting effects.

To make it possible to change my LightNode's position in my update method and when colliding with certain objects I wanted to make the variable global.

```
var light:SKLightNode!
```

I know how to get the iOS Version but using the code line above already makes my app crash on 7.1 before I can verify if it will work.

How can I only initialize this variable when using iOS 8 or higher?
I am using Swift and SpriteKit.

Thanks for your help,
Mikey

Comment: For purely stylistic points, you'd want to make this explicitly unwrapped anyway.  Implicitly unwrapped optionals really exist to support Objective-C interfaces.  In your pure swift code, where you're trying to indicate that some bit of functionality is optional, it's far cleaner to use explicitly unwrapped optionals.  It might also fix the linkage issues.

Comment: This isn't crashing for me on the simulator either way.  It doesn't crash until I try to actually initialize the SKLightNode.  With it just declared as "var light:SKLightNode!" the app runs fine.

Comment: The issue would seem to be somewhere else in your application.  Post the crash log and/or exception message.

Comment: Thanks David! I thought it would already stop working at that point because my app showed me that line after crashing. Works like a charm now with only initializing if iOS version is 8 or higher

Answer (score 2):

Only way I can imagine solving this problem is at the moment is storing `SKLightNode` as `Any?`. And casting if its not `nil`:

```
var light: Any? = {
    let iosVersion = NSString(string: UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion).doubleValue
    return (iosVersion >= 8 ? SKLightNode() : nil)
}()

if let light = light {
    println("yeah, we have \(light as SKLightNode)")
} else {
    println("nay, we have nothing")
}
```

Comment: Easy solution in the comments. Thanks anyway!